# How is Python automating C++ Application?

Tags: python, qt, scripting, automation

I do automation and currently automating an application made with QT (C++).
I use [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/) to do this using Python scripting language.

Can someone explain me exactly how a Python variable can be assigned a C++ Object?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to refer C++ built-in types (int, long, char, wchar_t, etc.) and arrays in Python code? If so you need to use `ctypes` Python package. Here is [an example of calling C++ dll function from Python](http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/articles/dll-in-c-for-python/). If you need to send Window message (like WM_CLICK) take a look at `ctypes.Structure` class. There are [some examples of C structures declared in Python code](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/win32structures.py).

EDIT: Currently I know 2 open source projects about QT GUI automation.

- [funq](https://github.com/parkouss/funq)
- [GammaRay](https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay/wiki/Getting-GammaRay)

Also it's possible to build and run QT app with accessibility features for [Windows UIA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375.aspx) and [Linux AT-SPI](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/en/AT-SPI_on_D-Bus).

Comment: I'm mainly talking about objects here. An Application that is written in C++ langauge using QT is being automated using a language like Python or Javascript. How is that actually happening is my question.

Comment: Do you mean UI testing automation? If using free tools probably you need `pyQT` and `PySide` packages or Windows UI Automation API (which is hard to use from Python, and it's complicated to learn - and not cross-platform). If this is a subject, let's talk about UI object representation (namely wrapper) that can contain some info about UI control and interact with it somehow. Such info format and interaction technologies highly depends on a platform: OS, GUI app framework (QT, WPF, MFC, wxWidgets or smth like that), having custom controls etc.

Comment: I don't know how Squish interacts with QT application process. Let's ask Squish developers about that. :) I still don't understand which **concrete** technical problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Updated the answer with more up-to-date info.